# Is there any way to install homebrew on iOS (jailbroken)

Tags: iphone, ios, terminal, homebrew, jailbreak

I'd like to install homebrew on my iPhone running iOS 10.3.3, which is jailbroken and has Terminal and NewTerm installed.

When I run `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -k -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib                                 
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/ruby           
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:                                          
        /usr/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib: can't
map segments into 16KB pages               
        /usr/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib: can't
map segments into 16KB pages               
        /usr/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib: can't
map segments into 16KB pages               
        /usr/lib/libruby.1.9.1.dylib: can't
map segments into 16KB pages               
Abort trap: 6
```

The command that I tried to use is the command that macOS uses to install homebrew.

Is there any way to successfully install homebrew on my iPhone?

This problem could be caused by the fact that my phone is only semi-jailbroken.

Ruby is installed, and my phone is semi-jailbroken (no tweaks, whenever I try to jailbreak with tweaks enabled, it gets stuck springing, respring two times and gets stuck at the same spot both times, and then reboots into regular iOS).

Comment: @Sam As an alternate solution, you can still install iOS apps without AppStore/Jailbreak over Lightning by using [Homebrew Sparkling](https://www.codefirst.org/homebrew-sparkling/) from your macOS.

Comment: @SebMa thank you for the link, that will be quite useful

Comment: Homebrew Sparkling's last update in github was "9 years ago" ... assuming there is zero chance this is still working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

Homebrew is designed for use on macOS systems. It is not intended for use on iOS, and the packages it downloads will not run on an iOS system. It cannot compile packages for iOS either, as the Xcode toolchain is not available for iOS.

Attempting to install Homebrew will be futile, and may render your device unusable.